# How can I read more rows in same select sentence?

Tags: sql, delphi, sql-server-2005

I am working with SQL Server 2005 and Delphi xe7 and using adoquery.

We have sales invoices for our customer. As the goverment wish we have to report totals of customers every month over 5000 (excluded from VAT).

This seems easy but we have different VAT values in invoices so I have to get correct values if the invoice has one VAT value or two or three.

Here is my basic select statement:

```
(mf.fis_aciklama1 like '%U SFA%')
or (mf.fis_aciklama1 like '%U ÝAF%')
```

This where clause is enough to getting sales invoices. This is ok.

I have read next row for 600 accounting number for shipment total and one next row for the VAT value. You can see the ABS function lines and subselects for this.

Now the question: how can I learn if I have to read next 2 rows or not?

How can I create a select statement like this with an "if"?

Actually I have an idea but I don't have pratice how the create statement for select this.

```
IF the fis_meblag0 of first row > fis_meblag0 of next + fis_meblag0 next+ next;
```

Then we have to read more row but but to write this in SQL.

```
select 
    mf.fis_tarih as Tarih,
    mf.fis_hesap_kod as HesapKod,    
    mh.muh_hesap_isim1 as Unvan,                                  
    mf.fis_aciklama1 as Aciklama,                                 
    mf.fis_yevmiye_no as Yno,                                     
    mf.fis_sira_no as Sno,                                         
    mf.fis_meblag0 as Tutar,                                       
    ABS((Select top 1 mf1.fis_meblag0 
         from dbo.MUHASEBE_FISLERI mf1 
         where mf.fis_yevmiye_no = mf1.fis_yevmiye_no
         and mf.fis_tur = mf1.fis_tur 
         and mf1.fis_RECno = mf.fis_RECno + 1 
         and left(mf1.fis_hesap_kod, 3) = '600')) as Matrah,  
    ABS((Select top 1 mf2.fis_meblag0 
         from dbo.MUHASEBE_FISLERI mf2     
         where mf.fis_yevmiye_no = mf2.fis_yevmiye_no 
         and mf.fis_tur = mf2.fis_tur 
         and mf2.fis_RECno = mf.fis_RECno + 2 
         and left(mf2.fis_hesap_kod, 3) = '391')) as KDV,  
    cr.cari_VergiKimlikNo as Vno 
from 
    dbo.MUHASEBE_FISLERI mf                                              
left join 
    dbo.MUHASEBE_HESAP_PLANI mh ON mf.fis_hesap_kod = mh.muh_hesap_kod  
left join 
    dbo.CARI_HESAPLAR cr ON mf.fis_hesap_kod = cr.cari_kod   
where
    mf.fis_tarih >= '20130501' 
    and mf.fis_tarih <= '20130531'  
    and ((mf.fis_aciklama1 like '%U SFA%') 
           or (mf.fis_aciklama1 like '%U ÝAF%'))
order by 
    mf.fis_hesap_kod
```

Here is my table structure

```
fis_RECno           Integer IDENTITY
fis_RECid_DBCno     Smallint
fis_RECid_RECno     Integer
fis_SpecRECno       Integer
fis_iptal           Bit
fis_fileid          Smallint
fis_hidden          Bit
fis_kilitli         Bit
fis_degisti         Bit
fis_checksum        Integer
fis_create_user     Smallint
fis_create_date     DateTime
fis_lastup_user     Smallint
fis_lastup_date     DateTime
fis_special1        Nvarchar(4)
fis_special2        Nvarchar(4)
fis_special3        Nvarchar(4)
fis_firmano         Integer                Firma No
fis_subeno          Integer                Sube No
fis_maliyil         Integer                Mali Yil
fis_tarih           DateTime               Fis Tarihi
fis_sira_no         Integer                Fis Sira No
fis_tur             Tinyint                Fis Türü
fis_hesap_kod       Nvarchar(25)           Fis Hesap Kodu
fis_satir_no        Integer                Fis Satir No
fis_aciklama1       Nvarchar(127)          Açiklama
fis_meblag0         Float                  Yerli döviz cinsinden meblag
fis_meblag1         Float                  Alternatif döviz cinsinden meblag
fis_meblag2         Float                  Orjinal döviz cinsinden meblag
fis_meblag3         Float                  Stok hesabi ise ana birimden miktari
fis_meblag4         Float                  Stok hesabi ise 2. birimden miktari
fis_meblag5         Float                  Stok hesabi ise 3. birimden miktari
fis_meblag6         Float                  Stok hesabi ise 4. birimden miktari
fis_sorumluluk_kodu Nvarchar(25)           Sorumluluk Merkezi
fis_ticari_tip      Tinyint                Ticari Tip Kodu
fis_ticari_DBCno    Smallint               Ilgili Ticari Kayda Baglanti DBCNO
fis_ticari_RECno    Integer                Ilgili Ticari Kayda Baglanti RECNO
fis_kurfarkifl      Bit                    Kur Farki Var mi?
fis_ticari_evraktip Tinyint                Ticari Evrak Tipi
fis_tic_evrak_seri  dbo.nvarchar_evrakseri Ticari Evrak Seri no
fis_tic_evrak_sira  Integer                Ticari Evrak Sira No
fis_tic_belgeno     dbo.nvarchar_belgeno   Ticari Evrak Belge No
fis_tic_belgetarihi DateTime               Belge Tarihi
fis_yevmiye_no      Integer                Fis Yevmiye No
fis_katagori        Smallint               Fis Kategori
fis_evrak_DBCno     Smallint
fis_fmahsup_tipi    Tinyint                Fis Mahsup Tipi
fis_fozelmahkod     Nvarchar(25)           Özel Mahsup Kodu
fis_grupkodu        Nvarchar(4)            Fis Grup Kodu
fis_aktif_pasif     Tinyint                Aktif Fis - Pasif Fis
fis_proje_kodu      Nvarchar(25)
```

Comment: We need more info. Please note that terms like *fis_aciklama1* or *fis_sira_no* have absolutely no meaning for English speakers. We need your table structure. We need sample data from your query.

Comment: You have a number of cases where you use `SELECT TOP 1 ....` but you're *not* specifying an `ORDER BY` - this is really bad practice - you want to the **first** row - but you're not saying **first ordered by what criteria** . Basically, you'll get a random "first" row ......

Comment: Hi, i have tried to paste table structure but it has not accepted.

Comment: @marc_s ;

The order is done in the reporting stage and fats report does the job. Group by the lines for customer codes and give me totals. 

The records are already date based so I have only the get the record between two dates. 

So in this way, i allways get the first record for the selected date.

Comment: If you don't have an `ORDER BY` in your `SELECT`, then there **IS NO ORDER** in SQL Server. Your `SELECT TOP 1 ....` is giving you **one row** - but it's arbitrary as to **which one** ......

Comment: Sorry Jan Dogen;  i have tried to paste table structure but it has not accepted.

Table structure is very long and fis aciklama1 is a string field of record type explanation (sale invoice, income, checks etc) and  sira_no is the basic line number. 

I know they are not in english but i dont have enough english to convert all of them too. 

Regards

Comment: @ikutuay Surely you can edit your post and edit your table structure in **as text**. Make sure you indent four spaces and align columns properly with spaces, not tabs. If you do that beforehand in an editor it's a simple copy/paste.

Comment: @marc_s;

The Main select if getting the total of invoice, first subsuery is getting the total of shipment, and the last subquery is getting VAT 

mf.fis_RECno is the identity field

Comment: @JanDoggen;

I have tried to paste it. It said need to be formatted. I hve edited all lines but it doen accept again. Byt the way ;

 http://www.mikro.com.tr/help/Library/Diger/DBYapisi_v14/Tablolar/muhasebe_fisleri.htm 

Here is the link for structure.

Comment: @ikutluay **Then why can I??** Took me 4-5 minutes. Now you do the translations and (**second time**) give sample data.

Comment: I have add more subqueries and give them mf.fis_RECno + 3, mf.fis_RECno + 4,mf.fis_RECno + 5 and mf.fis_RECno + 6. 

I know this is monkey testing but it worked. If more VAT exists, it is getting the vaules, otherways it get nulls, which is ok for me..